# MaxUserPort setting seems to be ignored

Tags: windows, tcpip

One of my .NET applications is getting the following exception when firing ~300 HTTP requests in a span of about 1 minute:

```
System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted
```

The only advice I could find on this was to adjust the `MaxUserPort` setting in the registry under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters`.

Even though I've set this setting to the maximum possible value the exception still occurs.

Answer (score 2):

It turned out that there is one more way to set limit of maximum open ports using the `netsh` service.

You can check the current value with:

```
netsh int ipv4 show dynamicport tcp
```

In my case it was set to 256. You can easily change it with:

```
netsh int ipv4 set dynamic tcp start=45000 num=10000
```

No restart required.

The reason for this problem is that even if you properly dispose `HttpClient` objects in .NET, the sockets still remain in `TIME_WAIT` state for some time. Therefore, even though the connections were sequential the limit was still relevant.

Answer (score 1):

By default, TCP ports are not closed immediately and remain in a TIME_WAIT state for 120 seconds.

Decreasing this setting `TcpTimedWaitDelay` to 30 seconds and setting the `StrictTimeWaitSeqCheck` to 1 may improve your TCP performance.

https://support.solarwinds.com/SuccessCenter/s/article/Tweaking-Windows-Server-performance-to-prevent-port-exhaustion-when-using-Orion-modules